# Apt search sees signal-desktop apt install doesn't

Tags: debian, apt, chrome-book, chrome-os, signal-messenger

I'm trying to install signal-desktop on chrome-os chromebook with linux(debian) terminal

All tutorials on how to do it copy and paste instructions from official [website](https://signal.org/download/linux/):

```bash
# NOTE: These instructions only work for 64 bit Debian-based
# Linux distributions such as Ubuntu, Mint etc.

# 1. Install our official public software signing key
wget -O- https://updates.signal.org/desktop/apt/keys.asc | gpg --dearmor > signal-desktop-keyring.gpg
cat signal-desktop-keyring.gpg | sudo tee -a /usr/share/keyrings/signal-desktop-keyring.gpg > /dev/null

# 2. Add our repository to your list of repositories
echo 'deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/signal-desktop-keyring.gpg] https://updates.signal.org/desktop/apt xenial main' |\
  sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list

# 3. Update your package database and install signal
sudo apt update && sudo apt install signal-desktop
```

After adding the signal repository I have used:

```bash
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

Following search is able to find the package:

```bash
sudo apt search signal-desktop
```

```
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
signal-desktop/xenial 5.62.0 amd64
  Private messaging from your desktop

signal-desktop-beta/xenial 5.63.0-beta.3 amd64
  Private messaging from your desktop
```

But trying to install it fails to find it:

```bash
sudo apt install signal-desktop
```

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package signal-desktop
```

I have read following tutorials on how to install signal on chrome-os but as mentioned earlier they all contain the same instructions:
[howtogeek](https://www.howtogeek.com/730644/how-to-install-signal-for-desktop-on-a-chromebook/)
[chromeunboxed](https://chromeunboxed.com/installing-signal-for-desktop-on-your-chromebook-2021-edition/)
[moyens](https://uk.moyens.net/how-to/how-to-install-signal-on-chromebook/)
[androidguys](https://www.androidguys.com/tips-tools/install-signal-chromebook/)
[bollyinside](https://www.bollyinside.com/articles/how-to-install-signal-on-your-chromebook/)

I have also tried following:

```bash
sudo apt update --fix-missing
sudo apt install -f
sudo apt clean
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt install -t ubuntu signal-desktop
sudo apt install -t xenial signal-desktop
sudo apt install signal-desktop=5.62.0
```

My current `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list`:

```
deb [arch=amd64] https://updates.signal.org/desktop/apt xenial main
```

Answer (score 0):

I gave up, instead I switched the debian container to arch: [tut](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Chrome_OS_devices/Crostini#Replacing_the_default_Debian_Linux_container_with_Arch_Linux)

And installed from aur with patch from comments: [aur](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/signal-desktop-beta#comment-880073)

Works well for now, only minor issue is that after clicking on the signal icon in chrome-os it opens as separate app so it defaults to the penguin icon